# Form input placeholder disappears in responsive mode

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm using this free theme - https://fasterthemes.com/demo/mywiki-wordpress-theme/ but apparently the placeholder text in the search bar disappears when I move to responsive mode. The text is there but it's just not visible.

Any help to fix this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :
[image]

```
@media (min-width: 241px) and (max-width:768px)
{
   #s::placeholder 
   {
       color:000;
   }
}
```

if not work media query :

```
#s::placeholder 
 {
      color:000;
 }
```

Comment: Apparently, it doesn't work. I tried both. I'm not sure why. I even removed all the additional CSS on WordPress customizer.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere the color white is set for the placeholder.
Try to set the color you want as important.

I hope, I helped you

```css
input#s::placeholder {
    color: black !important;
}
```